# Python (Pandas) How to merge 2 dataframes with different dates in incremental order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I am trying to merge 2 dataframes by date index in order. Is this possible?

A sample code of what I need to manipulate

Link for sg_df:[https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/%5ESTI?P=^STI?period1=1442102400&period2=1599955200&interval=1mo&events=history](https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/%5ESTI?P=%5ESTI?period1=1442102400&period2=1599955200&interval=1mo&events=history)

Link for facemask_compliance_df: https://today.yougov.com/topics/international/articles-reports/2020/05/18/international-covid-19-tracker-update-18-may (YouGov COVID-19 behaviour changes tracker: Wearing a face mask when in public places)

```
# Singapore Index
# Read file
# Format Date
# index date column for easy referencing
sg_df = pd.read_csv("^STI.csv")
conv = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y")
sg_df["Date"] = sg_df["Date"].apply(conv)
sg_df.sort_values("Date", inplace = True)
sg_df.set_index("Date", inplace = True)

# Will wear face mask in public
# Read file
# Format Date, Removing time
# index date column for easy referencing
facemask_compliance_df = pd.read_csv("yougov-chart.csv")
convert1 = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") 
facemask_compliance_df["DateTime"] = facemask_compliance_df["DateTime"].apply(convert1).dt.date
facemask_compliance_df.sort_values("DateTime", inplace = True)
facemask_compliance_df.set_index("DateTime", inplace = True)

sg_df = sg_df.merge(facemask_compliance_df["Singapore"], left_index = True, right_index = True, how = "outer").sort_index()
```

and I wish to output a table kind of like this.

[image]

Kindly let me know if you need any more info, I will kindly provide them to you shortly if I am able to.

Edit:

This is the issue

[image]

data from yougov-chart

[image]

I think it is reading the dates even when it is not from Singapore

Comment: So need sorting? Or avoiding sorting? There are datetimeindex? Because in sample data not.

Comment: Hello @jezrael, I will provide some now. Give me a moment. Yes I need the dates to be sorted

Comment: Hello @jezrael, I tried your moethod and this on shows the intercept of both dataframes

Comment: added answer for working with `DatetimeIndex`.

Comment: I will test it out right now. Thank you for your time @jezrael

Comment: Also changed data for reading files. If want use yours only change `facemask_compliance_df["DateTime"] = facemask_compliance_df["DateTime"].apply(convert1).dt.date` to `facemask_compliance_df["DateTime"] = facemask_compliance_df["DateTime"].apply(convert1).dt.floor('d')`

Comment: May I ask what does this do?

Comment: It remove times from dates, but it stay datetimes for match second DatetimeIndex (else no match because datetimeindwex and python object dates)

Comment: cool cool! Thank you for clarifying! Learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use parameters `parse_dates` and `index_col` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for DatetimeIndex in both and in second remove times by [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
sg_df = pd.read_csv("^STI.csv", 
                    parse_dates=['Date'], 
                    index_col=['Date'])

facemask_compliance_df = pd.read_csv("yougov-chart.csv", 
                                     parse_dates=['DateTime'],
                                     index_col=['DateTime'])
facemask_compliance_df["DateTime"] = facemask_compliance_df["DateTime"].dt.floor('d')
```

Then use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by index by outer join and then sort index by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = sg_df.merge(facemask_compliance_df, 
                 left_index=True, 
                 right_index=True, 
                 how='outer').sort_index()
print (df)
            Mask Compliance  US_GDP_Thousands
Date                                         
2016-02-01             37.0               NaN
2017-07-01             73.0               NaN
2019-10-01             85.0               NaN
2020-02-21             27.0              50.0
2020-03-18              NaN              55.0
2020-03-19              NaN              60.0
2020-03-25              NaN              65.0
2020-04-03              NaN              70.0
2020-05-14              NaN              75.0
```

Comment: hello @jezrael sorry to trouble you again but I have 4 columns in facemask_compliance_df. To signify 4 different countries. For some reason, when merging, the program will take my index of other countries as well which makes a whole row empty, only with the index'd date. Let me show you my updated code above.

Comment: @HOA - Do you think problem is with data from question?

Comment: I don't think the data has any problem. I just posted the issue

Comment: So e.g. `25/02/2020` is in both DaatFrames and no match?

Comment: I have updated with a new picture! It brought in all dates including from other columns

Comment: @HOA - What is `facemask_compliance_df.index.intersection(sg_df.index)` before `merge` ?

Comment: Sorry which line are you refering to? I can't find that particular line

Comment: @HOA - So maybe I can explain. There are no values because no values of both DatatimeIndex matching - e.g. here match only `2020-02-21` or no data in original data. So if empty columns it means no matching data.

Comment: yes that is right! Is there a way to only take values from Singapore column? If not, How do you suggest I clean the data?

Comment: @HOA - Then try `df = sg_df.merge(facemask_compliance_df['Singapore'], 
                 left_index=True, 
                 right_index=True, 
                 how='outer').sort_index()`

Comment: I already did that but the output is as per the the picture I showed above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221568/discussion-between-jezrael-and-hoa).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

1. [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge to tables.

1.1. `on` to choose on which column to merge:

> Column or index level names to join on. These must be found in both DataFrames. If `on` is None and not merging on indexes then this defaults to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames.

1.2. `outer` option:

> outer: use union of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL full outer join; sort keys lexicographically.

2. [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to sort by date

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("^STI.csv")

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date)

df2 = pd.read_csv("yougov-chart.csv")

df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.DateTime)

result = df2.merge(df1, on='Date', how='outer')
result = result.sort_values('Date')

print(result)
```

Output:

```
        Date  US_GDP_Thousands  Mask Compliance
6 2016-02-01               NaN             37.0
7 2017-07-01               NaN             73.0
8 2019-10-01               NaN             85.0
0 2020-02-21              50.0             27.0
1 2020-03-18              55.0              NaN
2 2020-03-19              60.0              NaN
3 2020-03-25              65.0              NaN
4 2020-04-03              70.0              NaN
5 2020-05-14              75.0              NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will test this out immediately!

Comment: Hello @Aviv Yanic, Yes! This is the result I am looking for! However I am unable to replicate this with my data! Could you kindly take a look at my updated question please?

Comment: Yes :) Tried to download the second dataset from [link] yet haven't found it. Could you provide another link to the dataset?

Comment: I can't! Thats the link! You have to scroll down to the part where they are showing (YouGov COVID-19 behaviour changes tracker: Wearing a face mask when in public places) there is a 3lined button there to download the csv file. Before downloading, you can unselect all countries and only select Singapore

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate this. @Aviv Yaniv

Comment: @HOA Welcome :) Check again the code - updated it to load  the dates (from line ~300 you can see that it merged (it merged all, yet from that line the dates overlap))

Comment: Hmm can't seem to give both of you the answer but jezrael managed to get it down to 1 line but thank you @Aviv Yaniv

Answer (score 0):

If i remember right In numpy you can do v.stack or h.stack. depends on how you want to join them together.

in pandas there was something like concatenate https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html which i used for merging dataframes

Comment: Thank you for your kind input! I will test this out right now!